# How to calculate BootTime from previous rows from Reboot column which contains time for Initiated and Completed entries - (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

### Need help to calculate BootTime in Python. I have a data set as shown below.

```
  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed
```

Expected output is as shown below

```
  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot BootTime
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated 00:00:00
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated 00:00:00
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed 06:03:00
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated 00:00:00
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed 00:01:00
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed 08:37:00
```

---

I tried below code but for BootTime for row 3 and 4 is wrong as I am interested to calculate BootTime from Initiated to Completed. I am also fine if I am able to calculate BootTime against Completed rows from previous Initiated time for each MacAddress.

My code is as shown below

---

```
import pandas as pd 
# Create data. 
d = {'MacAddress': ['Karan', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Karan'],
     'Datetime': ['2015-02-24 19:12:00', '2015-02-24 21:38:00', '2015-02-25 03:41:00', \
                  '2015-02-25 03:44:00', '2015-02-25 03:45:00', '2015-02-25 03:49:00'],
     'Reboot': ['Initiated', 'Initiated', 'Completed', 'Initiated', 'Completed', 'Completed']}

#d = {'MacAddress': 'Karan', 'Datetime': '2015-02-24 19:12:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-24 21:38:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:41:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:44:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:45:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Karan', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:49:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = ['MacAddress', 'Datetime', 'Reboot'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])).tz_localize('UTC')
print (df)
#df.groupby('MacAddress')['Datetime'].diff()
df=df.assign(BootTime=df.groupby('MacAddress').Datetime.apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0]))
print (df)
```

---

I got output from above code as shown below

```
  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed

  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot BootTime
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated 00:00:00
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated 00:00:00
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed 06:03:00
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated 06:06:00
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed 06:07:00
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed 08:37:00
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only change you should do is your 'reference' value for claculation (x.shift(1) instead of x.loc[0]) and a little cleanup routine.
This should be the solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create data.
d = {'MacAddress': ['Karan', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Shreya', 'Karan'],
 'Datetime': ['2015-02-24 19:12:00', '2015-02-24 21:38:00', '2015-02-25 03:41:00', \
              '2015-02-25 03:44:00', '2015-02-25 03:45:00', '2015-02-25 03:49:00'],
 'Reboot': ['Initiated', 'Initiated', 'Completed', 'Initiated', 'Completed', 'Completed']}

# d = {'MacAddress': 'Karan', 'Datetime': '2015-02-24 19:12:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-24 21:38:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:41:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:44:00', 'Reboot': 'Initiated'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Shreya', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:45:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}, \
#    {'MacAddress': 'Karan', 'Datetime': '2015-02-25 03:49:00', 'Reboot': 'Completed'}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['MacAddress', 'Datetime', 'Reboot'])
df['Datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])).tz_localize('UTC')
print (df)
# df.groupby('MacAddress')['Datetime'].diff()
df = df.assign(BootTime=df.groupby('MacAddress').Datetime.apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(1)))
# Reset "Initiated" values
# But i used a dummy calculation for 0-Datetime-Diff value, sorry for that
df.loc[df['Reboot'] == "Initiated", 'BootTime'] = pd.to_datetime(0).tz_localize("UTC") - pd.to_datetime(0).tz_localize("UTC")
print(df)
```

My output:

```
  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed
  MacAddress                  Datetime     Reboot        BootTime
0      Karan 2015-02-24 19:12:00+00:00  Initiated 0 days 00:00:00
1     Shreya 2015-02-24 21:38:00+00:00  Initiated 0 days 00:00:00
2     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:41:00+00:00  Completed 0 days 06:03:00
3     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:44:00+00:00  Initiated 0 days 00:00:00
4     Shreya 2015-02-25 03:45:00+00:00  Completed 0 days 00:01:00
5      Karan 2015-02-25 03:49:00+00:00  Completed 0 days 08:37:00
```